# Extract the real part of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am loading some data from a file, do a transformation and then extract the real part, however, the np.real function does not seem to work. It prints:

[[(0.99023793104890667+0.034016079376604003j) 0.9905214315431583
  0.99033818364852688 ..., 0.86609847609098078 0.87048246890045189 None]]

where clearly the first element is complex.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
import os.path
import PLVHilbertImplementation as pet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Likelihood_gen as lg

#for the interictal files
for j in range(1, 2, 1):
    filename = '/home/kam/Documents/kaggle/Dog_5/Dog_5_interictal_segment_' + str(j).zfill(4) + '.mat'
    PLVs=[]
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        #For the files that exist do this
        data=sio.loadmat(filename)['interictal_segment_1'][0][0][0][1:1024]
        numchannels, numpoints = data.shape
        label=np.ones((1,numpoints))
        for i in range(0, 2, 1):
            for j in range(i+1, 2, 1):



       PLVs.append(np.asarray((pet.PLV(data[i,:],np.transpose(data[j,:]), 1024, 5, 128))))
                print(np.real(PLVs)) #this is where the problem is




       # Metric=np.sum(np.exp(np.real(np.asarray(PLVs)),1))
       # plt.plot(Metric)
       # plt.show

    else:
        print('no', filename)
        break


#for the preictal files
for j in range(1, 1, 1):
    filename = 'Dog_1_preictal_segment_' + str(j).zfill(4) + '.mat'
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        data=sio.loadmat(filename)[0][0][0]
        numchannels, numpoints = shape(data)
        print(numchannels)
    else:
        print('no', filename)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[(0.99023793104890667+0.034016079376604003j) 0.9905214315431583
  0.99033818364852688 ..., 0.86609847609098078 0.87048246890045189 None]]
```

there are several clues that this is not an ordinary array of complex floats, which is what the `.real` method is meant for.

The complex number is enclosed in `()`

Not like:

```
In [1011]: np.arange(5)+np.arange(2,7)*1j
Out[1011]: array([ 0.+2.j,  1.+3.j,  2.+4.j,  3.+5.j,  4.+6.j])

In [1013]: (np.arange(5)+np.arange(2,7)*1j).real
Out[1013]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

And there's a `None` in the array.  `nan` is a valid float, not `None`.

I'm guessing the shape is 2d (but you should print that), and that the dtype is object - but you need to show that.

I can create something that prints like this with:

```
In [1014]: data=np.empty((5,),dtype=object)  # 1d, could be 2

In [1015]: data     # default empty fill None
Out[1015]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)

In [1016]: data[0]=1+3.j

In [1017]: data[1:4]=[1.2,3,4.2]

In [1018]: data    # the repr display
Out[1018]: array([(1+3j), 1.2, 3, 4.2, None], dtype=object)

In [1019]: print(data)   # the str display
[(1+3j) 1.2 3 4.2 None]

In [1021]: data.real
Out[1021]: array([(1+3j), 1.2, 3, 4.2, None], dtype=object)

In [1022]: data[0].real
Out[1022]: 1.0
```

convert to complex  (could slice off the `None` with `data[:-1]`)

```
In [1027]: data.astype(complex)
Out[1027]: array([ 1.0 +3.j,  1.2 +0.j,  3.0 +0.j,  4.2 +0.j,  nan+nanj])

In [1028]: data.astype(complex).real
Out[1028]: array([ 1. ,  1.2,  3. ,  4.2,  nan])
```

Comment: The .astype(complex) was the crucial part without which .real does not work. Great job pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

real should be used as numpy array obj function

```
a = numpy.array([1+2j, 3+4j])
print a.real

array([ 1.,  3.])
```

Comment: @KamyarGhofrani what is data before you convert to real?

Comment: I am reading a .mat file, which returns a dictionary. then I read values from the dictionary and put them in a list. I then convert the list to an np array using np.asarray.

Comment: @KamyarGhofrani I mean could you post some sample data before you use real function

Comment: Here is a link to the files, I hope this works. [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bw22NMRjgDGLS3RVVEdHUEJLUjg&usp=sharing]

Comment: Seems like you have `None` element in array that you read. You might need to replace that by some number first, says 0.